# Write a program NumberCount that counts the numbers (including integers and floating point values) in one or more text files. (Due today lol)

Tags: java

INSTRUCTIONS:
Write a program NumberCount that counts the numbers (including integers and floating point values) in
one or more text files. Note that only numbers separated by whitespace characters are counted, i.e., only
those numbers that can be read by either readInt() or readDouble() are considered.

So iv been trying to get this program to read text files and the title is pretty much the instructions but it does not want to read my textfiles that i have in the project folder (i tried moving it a bunch of times but anywhere i put it it didnt load up) This is my code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class NumberCount implements Runnable {
    private static int combinedCount = 0;

    public static synchronized int getCombinedCount() {
        return combinedCount;
    }

    public synchronized void setCombinedCount( int combinedCount) {
        this.combinedCount = combinedCount;
    }

    String filename;

    NumberCount(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    NumberCount() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        String fileText = this.getTextFromFile(filename);
        System.out.println(filename + ": " + countNumbers(fileText));

        setCombinedCount(getCombinedCount() + countNumbers(fileText));
    }

    String getTextFromFile(String filename) {

        try {
            String data = "";
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename)));

            String st; 
            while ((st = br.readLine()) !=null) {
                data += "\n" + st; 

            }

            data = data.replaceAll("\n", " ");

            return data;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to retrieve text from file: " + filename );
            return "";
        }

    }

    int countNumbers(String text) {
        int count = 0;

        String words[] = text.split(" ");

        for (String word : words) {
            try {

                Integer.parseInt(word);
                Float.parseFloat(word);
                count++;

            } catch (Exception e)  {
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

    String helpMessage() {
        String data = "Please call as NumberCount <list of file names>\n";
        data += "File names to be present in the same directory";
        return data;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println(new NumberCount().helpMessage());
        } else {

            Thread threads[] = new Thread[args.length];
            int i = 0;

            for (String filename : args) {
                NumberCount nc = new NumberCount(filename);
                threads[i] = new Thread(nc);

                threads[i++].start();
            }

            try {

                for(Thread t : threads) {
                    t.join();
                }
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("combined count: " + getCombinedCount());

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: well one good start is to share with us how are you really passing the filenames as java arguments. The second one would be that the Java Application(user that invoked it) has really access privileges to that directory in order to read the files. Also a last note, dont call `countNumbers()` twice for efficiency.

Comment: when i run the debug i can see that my program goes right to the message of not finding any files because the args is 0 but im looking for a way to pass file path as an arg.